Vector $p$-norm submultiplicativity
Let $X=M_n(\mathbb R)$.
Is the $p$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by : $$||x||_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
with $p \in [1,\infty[$ submultiplicative : $||xy||_p \leq ||x||_p||y||_p$ forall $x,y \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ ?
I know it's true for $p=1$, $p=2$ but not true for $p=\infty$. What about other values of $p$ ?
Edit : The norm on $M_n(\mathbb R)$ in this case is the norm of the vector of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.
Thanks for help.

Clarifying question: Is $xy$ pointwise multiplication of the matrices seen as vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$ or is it regular matrix multiplication?

@LeoSera as vectors in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}
